# What is the fastest way in Cython to create a new array from an existing array and a variable

Tags: python, arrays, cython, cpython

Suppose I have an array

```
from array import array
myarr = array('l', [1, 2, 3])
```

and a variable:
`myvar = 4`
what is the fastest way to create a new array:

```
newarray = array('l', [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

You can assume all elements are of 'long' type

I have tried to create a new array and use `array.append()`
not sure if it is fastest. I was thinking of using `memoryview` like:
`malloc(4*sizeof(long))`
but I don't know how to copy a shorter array into part of the memoryview. then insert last element into last position.

I am fairly new to Cython. Thanks for any help!

Update:
I compared the following three methods:

**Cython:** [100000 loops, best of 3: 5.94 µs per loop]

```
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc

def cappend(long[:] arr, long var, size_t N):
    cdef long[:] result = <long[:(N+1)]>malloc((N+1)*sizeof(long))
    result.base[:N] = arr
    result.base[N] = var
    return result
```

**array:** [1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.21 µs per loop]

```
from array import array
import copy
def pyappend(arr, x):
    result = copy.copy(arr)
    result.append(x)
    return result
```

**list append:** [1000000 loops, best of 3: 480 ns per loop]

```
def pylistappend(lst, x):
    result = lst[:]
    result.append(x)
    return result
```

is there hope to improve the cython part and beat the array one?

Comment: Are you actually using Cython - as in [this thing](http://cython.org/) - or did you get it mixed up with something else? Also, why did you pick `array.array` arrays? It's not clear why you need them.

Comment: Going by the [docs](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/array.html#cloning-extending-arrays), probably just clone and append.

Comment: You'll probably want to put explicit types on your variables, though.

Comment: @user2357112 yes I am using cython. I use `array.array` for type enforced array. I could use np.array as well. the question is the same. I am not sure this is fastest in the sense of pure C implementation, no overhead python type checking. 
and yeah assume I cdef the variable as `long`

Comment: This is something you should not be doing often - it is never really fast because it usually has to copy all the data in the old array. The reason `list` is the fastest option is that it is designed to be resized, so allocates more space than it needs to give it room to expand. If you want something quick then you should do the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cython gives us more access to the internals of `array.array` than the "normal" python, so we can utilize it to speed up the code:

1. almost by factor `7` for your small example (by eliminating most of the overhead).
2. by factor `2` for larger inputs by eliminating an unnecessary array-copy.

Read on for more details.

---

It's a little bit unusual to try to optimize a function for such small input, but not without (at least theoretical) interest.

So let's start with your functions as baseline:

```
a=array('l', [1,2,3])
%timeit pyappend(a, 8)
1.03 µs ± 10.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

lst=[1,2,3]
%timeit pylistappend(lst, 8)
279 ns ± 6.03 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

We must be aware: what we are measuring is not the cost of copying but the cost of overhead (python interpreter, calling functions and so on), for example there is no difference whether `a` has 3  or 5 elements:

```
a=array('l', range(5))
%timeit pyappend(a, 8)
1.03 µs ± 6.76 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

In the array-version, we have more overhead because we have indirection via `copy` module, we can try to eliminate that:

```
def pyappend2(arr, x): 
      result = array('l',arr)                   
      result.append(x)                               
      return result

%timeit pyappend2(a, 8)
496 ns ± 5.04 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

That is faster. Now let's use cython - this would eliminate the interpreter costs:

```
 %%cython
 def cylistappend(lst, x):      
     result = lst[:]                                  
     result.append(x)                            
     return result

 %%cython
 from cpython cimport array
 def cyappend(array.array arr, long long int x):
      cdef array.array res = array.array('l', arr)
      res.append(x)
      return res   

 %timeit cylistappend(lst, 8)
 193 ns ± 12.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
 %%timeit cyappend(a, 8)
 421 ns ± 8.08 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

The cython versions is about 33% faster for `list` and about 10% faster for `array`. The constructor `array.array()` expects an iterable, but we already have an `array.array`, so we use the functionality from `cpython` to get access to internals of the `array.array` object and improve the situation a little:

```
 %%cython
 from cpython cimport array
 def cyappend2(array.array arr, long long int x):
     cdef array.array res = array.copy(arr)
     res.append(x)
     return res

 %timeit cyappend2(a, 8)
 305 ns ± 7.25 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

For the next step we need to know how `array.array` appends elements: Normally, [it over-allocates](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b3a77964ea89a488fc0e920e3db6d8477279f19b/Modules/arraymodule.c#L112), so `append()` has amortized cost `O(1)`, however after `array.copy` the new array is exactly the needed number of elements and the next `append` invokes reallocation. We need to change that (see [here](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/array.html#functions) for the description of the used functions):

```
  %%cython
  from cpython cimport array
  from libc.string cimport memcpy
  def cyappend3(array.array arr, long long int x):
           cdef Py_ssize_t n=len(arr)
           cdef array.array res = array.clone(arr,n+1,False)
           memcpy(res.data.as_voidptr, arr.data.as_voidptr, 8*n)#that is pretty sloppy..
           res.data.as_longlongs[n]=x
           return res

 %timeit cyappend3(a, 8)
 154 ns ± 1.34 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Similar to your function, the memory is over-allocated, so we don't need to call `resize()` any longer. Now we are faster than the `list` and almost 7 times faster than the original python version.

---

Let's compare timings for bigger array sizes (`a=array('l',range(1000))`, `lst=list(range(1000))`, where copying of the data makes most of the running time:

```
  pyappend             1.84 µs  #copy-module is slow!
  pyappend2            1.02 µs
  cyappend             0.94 µs  #cython no big help - we are copying twice
  cyappend2            0.90 µs  #still copying twice
  cyappend3            0.43 µs  #copying only once -> twice as fast!

  pylistappend         4.09 µs # needs to increment refs of integers
  cylistappend         3.85 µs # the same as above
```

Now, eliminating the unnecessary copy for `array.array` gives us the expected factor 2.

---

For even bigger arrays (`10000` elements), we see the following:

```
  pyappend             6.9 µs  #copy-module is slow!
  pyappend2            4.8 µs
  cyappend2            4.4 µs  
  cyappend3            4.4 µs
```

There is no longer a difference between the versions (if one discards the slow copy-module). The reason for this is the changed behavior of the `array.array` for such big number of elements: when copying it over-allocates thus avoiding the reallocation after the first `append()`.

We can easily check it:

```
b=array('l', array('l', range(10**3)))#emulate our functions
b.buffer_info()
[] (94481422849232, 1000)
b.append(1)
b.buffer_info()
[] (94481422860352, 1001) # another pointer address -> reallocated
...
b=array('l', array('l', range(10**4)))
b.buffer_info()
[](94481426290064, 10000)
b.append(33)
b.buffer_info()
[](94481426290064, 10001) # the same pointer address -> no reallocation!
```

Comment: great answer and detailed analysis! Thank you very much.